# Executing SQLLDR from within a PL-SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-loader

Hello and thanks in advance. I am running Oracle 11gR2 and want to try to execute an sql loader to insert data into an existing table. I am attempting this via Java stored proc in the database that will perform commands on the OS. The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get the call to invoke SQLLDR.EXE to work - error I have is: sqlldr not found (NOTE that lookup with PATH isnt done due to the Oracle executable being SETUID)

----------------------Sample Code------------------------------------------

```
declare
  l_ldr varchar2(1000) := '/u01/app/oracle/product/db/11.2.0.4/bin/sqlldr.exe control=C:\ad\controlfile.ctl, log=load.log, bad=load.bad,data=C:\somefile.txt';
  l_env varchar2(1000) := 'PATH=/bin:/u01/oracle/db/11.2.0.4/jdk/bin;';
  l_out varchar2(5000);
  l_ret varchar2(5000);


begin

 dbms_output.put_line(l_ldr);
  MSO_Java.dbcmd('sqlldr.exe',
                 l_ldr,
                 l_env,
                 'Y',
                 l_out,
                 l_ret);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_ret);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_out);
end;
```

--------------------------END CODE SAMPLE--------------------

Appreciate ANY help here. I know this can be done.....

Comment: Why would you invoke SQL*Loader from Oracle rather than defining an external table (which is using the same logic under the covers) so that you can just query the table to cause the file to be loaded?  Your command looks to be mixing Unix and Windows directory structures which can't possibly work.  If the database is running on Windows, sqlldr isn't in /u01/app.  If the database is running on Unix, the data file and control file isn't on the c:\ drive

Comment: Why would you have sqlldr.exe (or anything with a .exe extension) on what appears to be a Unix-y box, from the `/u01/...` paths? Are you confusing a Windows client machine with a non-Windows server? The C: paths for the control file etc. suggests there is some confusion somewhere...

Comment: Database runs on Redhat LINUX. Control file is on c. I just need to understand how I can succssfully call sqlloader. Thats it. Can anyone offer help with what I am asking? No, I do not want to use external tables right now....

Comment: You've got a stored procedure running on a linux database.  It can shell out and call SQL*Loader on the database server.  But that executable can't see files stored on your local machine unless something has been configured on the database server to mount a drive that you are sharing from your machine.  That would be an extremely odd architecture-- servers do not generally mount drives shared by clients.  If your server actually does mount a drive that your client is sharing, your command line would need to reference the path as the server sees it not the path as the client sees it.

Comment: You're trying to have a Java process on your Redhat server invoke a Windows executable on another machine. That isn't going to work. You could run the Linux version of SQL\*Loader but would have to make the control and data files available to that Linux process. The simplest way would be to move them to the Linux box; but then you might as well use an external table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**SQLLDR** doesn't have the option to be executed in a PL/SQL, but you can simulate a **SQLLDR** with PL/SQL.

Yeap this is posible, I created a stored procedure that works fine just with *REGEXP*, now the documentation is in spanish but as soon that I can I will translate this.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/srjefers/plSQL/tree/master/sqlLoader)

**Performence?** Yeah I now that simulate a SQLLDR will be affect the performance in the database but **NO**, is this the reason that I used *REGEXP*. That works fine for me loading masive data.

Another thing is that this PL/SQL gives you the opportunity to transform the data. You can use a ETL for that but sometimes that is not possible :(.

**THAT IS EASY TO UNDERSTAND :D!**